# How to find matching words in Text Box and Datagrid when VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true"?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have Datagrid and Text Box in my Form. Datagrid is showing me existing items in my stock. I use Text Box to search and set focus to that row which is matching with my Text Box. Now it is working fine when VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="false" but it is very slow and getting a lot RAM resource. 
Here is my code for this.

```
public IEnumerable<Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
        {
            var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
            foreach (var item in itemsSource)
            {
                var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow;
                if (null != row) yield return row;
            }
        }


        private void SearchBoxDataGrid_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = GetDataGridRows(AssortDataGrid);
            /// go through each row in the datagrid
            foreach (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow r in row)
            {
                DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)r.Item;
                // Get the state of what's in column 1 of the current row (in my case a string)
                string t = rv.Row["Ассортимент"].ToString().ToLower();
                if (t.StartsWith(SearchBoxDataGrid.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    AssortDataGrid.SelectedIndex = r.GetIndex();
                    AssortDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(AssortDataGrid.SelectedItem);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

What I want is to make it VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" but in this case my method is not working. I know why it is not working, my code will work only for showing part of Datagrid.
What do you recommend? How to fix this issue?  Any idea will be appreciated. If you give any working code it will be fantastic. I hope I could explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little coding and make it work. If anyone needs it in future please, use it.
Firstly I am creating List of Products

```
List<string> ProductList;
```

Then  on Load Method I list all my products to my Product List.

```
    SqlCommand commProc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.fGetProductNameFromId(ProductID) as ProductName from Assortment order by ProductName desc", MainWindow.conn);
    string str2;
    SqlDataReader dr2 = commProc2.ExecuteReader();
    ProductList = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        if (dr2.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                str2 = (string)dr2["ProductName"];
                ProductList.Insert(0, str2.ToLower ());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured while trying to fetch data\n" + ex.Message);
    }

    dr2.Close();
    dr2.Dispose();
```

After that I did some changes in SearchBoxDataGrid_TextChanged

```
    private void SearchBoxDataGrid_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int pos = 0;
        string typedString = SearchBoxDataGrid.Text.ToLower();
        foreach (string item in ProductList)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchBoxDataGrid.Text))
            {
                if (item.StartsWith(typedString))
                {
                    pos = ProductList.IndexOf(item);
                    AssortDataGrid.SelectedIndex = pos;
                    AssortDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(AssortDataGrid.SelectedItem);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Now it works when VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true".
That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization means that WPF will reuse the UI components, and simply replace the `DataContext` behind the components.

For example, if your Grid has 1000 items and only 10 are visible, it will only render around 14 UI items (extra items for scroll buffer), and scrolling simply replaces the `DataContext` behind these UI items instead of creating new UI elements for every item. If you didn't use `Virtualization`, it would create all 1000 UI items.

For your `Search` to work with Virutalization, you need to loop through the `DataContext` (`DataGrid.Items`) instead of through the UI components. This can either be done in the code-behind, or if you're using MVVM you can handle the `SeachCommand` in your `ViewModel`.

Comment: That is good idea, but I would like to see some codes. Is there any sample so i can get more information. You just showed me direction. Thanks for that also.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Can't think of any samples right now, but it should be simple to just loop through `DataGrid.Items`, check if the property bound in column 1 matches the search text, and if so get the UI element for that item and call `ScrollIntoView` with it.